# Outlook Email showing blank SharePoint list fields from 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am having an issue with the sharepoint 2010 Reusable workflow attached to a content type. Lets say content type as "test". In that there are fields I am populating in email body. When the workflow runs all fields populate except for 2 or 3 which are choice,multiline with history enabled and single line.
How do I troubleshoot this error?.....

[image: Outlook Email Body with missing fields which are entered in SharePoint list]

Answer (score 0):

**The root cause of this issue** is

- Enabling the **Append Changes** for the Multiline column.

[image]

The Multiline column with **Append Changes** will save each new change as a version (where **versioning** is a mandatory prerequisite to enable **Append Changes**). at the same time, the Multiline column value of the current version is **blank**! so it shows blank in your email!

**To overcome this issue**,

- Try to Disable `Append Changes` and in this case, you can use multiline in an email and create a workflow that tracks the field history.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. The append is already off on the column.
I figured out the issue by using SharePoint manager and found that the internal name is more than 32 characters limit. Hence it is not working in workflow.
I am currently working on getting another calculated column which points to this lengthy column to display in workflow.